# Why does my typescript function break when I use modular index on an array?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an image carousel/slider that has a function to get the next image like so:

```
getNext() {
    this.i = this.i===this.Artwks.length ? this.i : (this.i + 1)%this.Artwks.length;
    this.artworks.next(this.Artwks[this.i])
    this.getSlide();
}
```

This works beautifully and calls the getSlide function to show the correct image in an array.

My getPrev() function is almost exactly the same, yet

```
(this.i - 1)%this.Artwks.length;
```

seems to break it.

Artwks is an array, and i is a number initialised at 0. What is going on here?

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: I get "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'artTitle' of undefined" - does the array think the number is less than 0? ArtTitle is a field in an interface that sets up the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the i reaches the value equals 0, i - 1 equals -1, and with that index you are probably trying to reach an array which gives you the error. Try to do the following:

```
  getPrev() {
        this.i = this.i===this.Artwks.length ? this.i : this.i === 0 ? 1 : (this.i - 1 )%this.Artwks.length;
    ...
    }
```

or

```
this.i = this.i===this.Artwks.length || this.i === 0? this.i : (this.i - 1 )%this.Artwks.length;
```

Comment: In fairness - I didn't say how long the array was! Doh!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that negative numbers modulo a number will result in a negative number and thus a negative index which will be undefined.

`-1 % 10 === -1`

Answer (score 0):

A thought that i had was maybe try adding an if statement to only call getPrev() when your array is greater than 0 currently it aeems to be doing what your telling it to, no?

```
If(currDisplayPic > 0)
   getPrev();
```

Put that into a button to call it when uaer needs it

Sorry for having to edit im answering from my mobile and my post button was pressed prematurely.. Anyway

I may be wrong being that im still newish to programming JS and TS but as far as i know array can count up easily but going down it needs to know it can.. No?

Comment: Well I wanted to be able to cycle through the images so when it reaches 0 the index should go back to length-of-array?

Comment: Hm, I see the dilemma, I will run through a few ideas and see what i can cook up let me know if you get something going!